# How to separate module while avoid conflict in dependencies

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, swift-package-manager

I created a framework to modularise the integration of ads in apps.
To work, this framework needs other frameworks as dependencies (namely GoogleMobileAds).
The embedded frameworks have also some dependencies (for exemple : GoogleAppMeasurement).

This until here everything works fine.

The problem is when developing a main app.
The main app has firebase as a dependency. And firebase has GoogleAppMeasurement as a dependency as well.

Now we end-up with the same framework embedded twice in the app, generating warnings (as expected) and preventing us to upload the app to App Store connect.

The questions are : how to NOT embed the GoogleAppMeasurement framework twice?
Is there a way to optionally load the GoogleAppMeasurement dependencies in my own ad framework if the app doesn't have it yet?

Some precision :

- My ad framework is a normal framework (for now) using swift, not an xcframework.
- GoogleMobileAds is integrated in my framework by copy and past.
- GoogleAppMeasurement is an xcframework (with closed sources in objC)
- Firebase is integrated as a swift package loading its dependencies from other swift package wrapping a xcframework.
- I'm not using CocoaPods or Cartridge.

Thanks

Comment: You will not like this but... you should program to an interface, not to an implementation. Checkout "clean architecture". You have there clean, abstract code hidden behind protocols and value types. All dependencies are injected from one place.

Comment: I do like that. However, that's not what my problem is here. My ad package has interface for that purpose however, I still need to embed in my package the dependencies to Google ad and others. Which then conflict to other Framework...